# for(i=0;i<10000000000;++i) compiles to endless loop?

Tags: c, assembly, for-loop

I was running some tests to see how ++i and i++ translated to asm. I wrote a simple for :

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1000000;++i);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled it with **gcc test.c -O0 -o test**, and checked the asm with **objdump -d test**:

```
4004ed: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4004f0: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)  // i=0;
4004f7: eb 04                   jmp    4004fd <main+0x11>
4004f9: 83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)     // ++i;
4004fd: 81 7d fc 3f 42 0f 00    cmpl   $0xf423f,-0x4(%rbp) // 
400504: 7e f3                   jle    4004f9 <main+0xd>   //i<1000000;
400506: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
40050b: 5d                      pop    %rbp
40050c: c3                      retq
```

so far so good. The weird thing (if i understand asm code correctly) was when instead of i<1000000 i wrote i<10000000000. Exactly same for loop with stopping condition i<10000000000 translated to following assembler code :

```
4004ed: 48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
4004f0: c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
4004f7: 83 45 fc 01             addl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
4004fb: eb fa                   jmp    4004f7 <main+0xb>
```

which is endless loop per my understanding, cause exactly same asm was generated for :

```
 for(i=0;;++i);
```

The question is, is it really possible that it is compiled to endless loop? Why?
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04, x86_64.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you think `i` can hold `10000000000` on your architecture?

Comment: Use `long long int` for such large numbers. And check `limits.h` to get an idea about sizes of integral types.

Comment: Any sane compiler will generate exactly the same code for `i++` and `++i`, unless you actually use the result.

Comment: If you compile with optimizations, both all such loops should compile to *nothing*, because they obviously *do nothing*. If you compile without optimizations, your findings will probably be useless.

Comment: @haccks I guess int is small for such number, but here cmpl   $0xf423f,-0x4(%rbp) the number is not in an int, it is just a const, so i would expect from compiler to know how to deal with it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This happens because the maximum value of an `int` on your architecture can never reach 10000000000. It will overflow at some point before reaching that value. Thus, the condition `i < 10000000000` will always evaluate as true, meaning this is an infinite loop.

The compiler is able to deduct this at compile time, which is why it generates appropriate assembly for an infinite loop.

The compiler is able to warn you about this. For that to happen, you can enable the "extra" warning level with:

```
gcc -Wextra
```

GCC 4.8.2 for example will tell you:

```
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]
for (i = 0; i < 10000000000; ++i);
^
```

And it even tells you the specific warning option that exactly controls this type of warning (Wtype-limits).

Comment: Still, the OP used -O0 which should prevent any kind of optimizations. Or is this such a trivial one?

Comment: @BlackBear Yes, some trivial optimizations are performed even at O0.

Comment: @BlackBear removing what is essentially a constant comparison of false and true is pretty trivial. It's not warning about the comparison being constant that I'd criticise

Comment: @NikosC. Thanks, -Wextra is helpful in this case :
warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Wtype-limits]

Comment: @BlackBear -- its not a question of optimazation. If the code was not optimized the counter reached 2,147,483,647 the next increment would make it -2,147,483,646 and so would never be > 10,000,000,000.

Comment: @JamesAnderson What he meant was that at -O0, the assembly should have a comparison in it. The increment is still there, the comparison is not, because the compiler deducted that it's always true.

Comment: The most fully optimised version would be `eb fe` :)

Answer (score 5):

Integer range is: –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

You are like way above it.

Comment: The `int` range may be smaller or larger.  Per C11 §5.2.4.2.1 the _minimum_ range is -32767 to +32767.  Such a 16-bit range of -32768 to +32767 is commonly found in 2014 in embedded processors.

Comment: that's like int16 but 2014 processors do not use int16 anymore. If you have a very old processor ok, yes. But now almost every int is processed by int32

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht: Not the CPU running your microwave.

Comment: MicroChip made over billion of PICs processors in 2013. A very large share is 16-bit. - I think the largest.  C is very popular with such processors.  There is lots of money to be made programming with 16-bit `int`.  Show your figures to back up " 2014 processors do not use int16".

Comment: @JonasLibbrech [16-bit PIC24 MCUs and dsPIC® DSCs](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en_us/family/16bit/)

Comment: yeah i meant heavy duty cpu's :p, and yet i forgot microprocessors :p, my fault!

Answer (score 4):

If 10000000000 is outside the range of int, but inside the range of long or long long, for your compiler, then i < 10000000000 casts i to long or long long before making the comparison.

Realising it will always be false, the compiler then removes the redundant comparison.

I should hope there'd been some sort of compiler warning.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused because you are using `int` for storing such big number.
As a result, the i [wraps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) around itself, and never reaches the termination condition of the for loop.
When you exceed the limit for the data types in C/C++, funny things can happen.
The compiler can detect these things at compile time, and therefore, generates the code for infinite loop in assembly language.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is:
 You can't store such a large number in "i".

Look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29 for more information.

"i" (the variable) can't reach 10000000000, thus the loop evaluates true always and runs infinite times.

You can either use a smaller number or another container for i, such as the multiprecision library of Boost:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the compiler sees that you are using a condition that can never be false, so the condition is simply never evaluated.

An `int` can never hold a value that is as large as `10000000000`, so the value will always be lower than that. When the variable reaches its maximum value and you try to increase it further, it will wrap around and start from its lowest possible value.

The same removal of the condition happens if you use a literal value of `true`:

```
for (i = 0; true; ++i);
```

The compiler will just make it a loop without a condition, it won't actually evaluate the `true` value on each iteration to see if it is still true.